# Overcome VBA InputBox Character Limit

Tags: excel, vba, limit, character, inputbox

The current function I use to collect text InputBox can't accept more than 255 characters apparently, and I need to be able to collect more than that? Is there a parameter or different function I can use to increase this limit?

Comment: Why an InputBox? A small form and textbox is nearly always a better idea.

Comment: @Remou ~ because that takes a lot more code and is not always easy for the new developer to use, whereas InputBox is highly accessible. Otherwise +1

Comment: ~ I don't think it will take a longer string, SOL... Follow @Remou's advice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To be pedantic, the Inputbox will let you type up to 255 characters, but it will only return 254 characters.

Beyond that, yes, you'll need to create a simple form with a textbox. Then just make a little "helper function" something like:

```
Function getBigInput(prompt As String) As String
    frmBigInputBox.Caption = prompt
    frmBigInputBox.Show
    getBigInput = frmBigInputBox.txtStuff.Text
End Function
```

or something like that...

Comment: shouldn't this be in a label like this `frmBigInputBox.myLabel.caption = prompt` otherwise everything is in the top bar of the form/window.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks BradC for the info that. My final code was roughly as follows, I have a button that calls the form that I created and positions it a bit as I was having some issues with the form being in the wrong spot the everytime after the first time I used.

```
Sub InsertNotesAttempt()
    NoteEntryForm.Show
    With NoteEntryForm
        .Top = 125
        .Left = 125
    End With
End Sub
```

The userform was a TextBox and two CommandButtons(Cancel and Ok). The code for the buttons was as follows:

```
Private Sub CancelButton_Click()
    Unload NoteEntryForm
End Sub

Private Sub OkButton_Click()
    Dim UserNotes As String

    UserNotes = NotesInput.Text

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    If UserNotes = "" Then
        NoteEntryForm.Hide
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Worksheets("Notes").ListObjects("Notes").ListRows.Add (1)
    Worksheets("Notes").Range("Notes").Cells(1, 1) = Date
    Worksheets("Notes").Range("Notes").Cells(1, 2) = UserNotes
    Worksheets("Notes").Range("Notes").Cells(1, 2).WrapText = True
    ' Crap fix to get the wrap to work. I noticed that after I inserted another row the previous rows
    ' word wrap property would kick in. So I just add in and delete a row to force that behaviour.
    Worksheets("Notes").ListObjects("Notes").ListRows.Add (1)
    Worksheets("Notes").Range("Notes").Item(1).Delete
    NotesInput.Text = vbNullString
    NotesInput.SetFocus ' Retains focus on text entry box instead of command button.
    NoteEntryForm.Hide
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't have enough rep to comment, but in the sub form_load for the helper you can add:

```
me.AutoCenter = True
```

Outside of that form, you can do it like this:

```
NoteEntryForm.Show
Forms("NoteEntryForm").AutoCenter = True
```

My Access forms get all confused when I go from my two extra monitors at work to my one extra monitor at home, and are sometimes lost in the corner.  This AutoCenter has made it into the form properties of every one of my forms.

Comment: Welcome to the site! This does not attempt to answer the posted question, as you know, and should be a comment. [Please use Answers exclusively to answer the question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/92107). To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have [sufficient reputation](//stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](//stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). In the meantime, please do not use answers to post comments.